# Helm Install MySQL InnoDB Cluster: tls.routerCertAndPKsecretName: secret 'my-mysql-innodbcluster-router-tls' not found in namespace 'default'

Tags: mysql, installation, kubernetes

When I [run the command from ArtifactHUB to install the `mysql-innodbcluster`](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/mysql-operator/mysql-innodbcluster?modal=install)

```
helm install my-mysql-innodbcluster mysql-operator/mysql-innodbcluster --version 2.0.4
```

I get the following error,

> Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: execution error at (`mysql-innodbcluster/templates/deployment_cluster.yaml:18:8`): tls.routerCertAndPKsecretName: secret 'my-mysql-innodbcluster-router-tls' not found in namespace 'default'

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions for deploying/creating a [MySQL InnoDB Cluster with Helm can be found here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-operator/en/mysql-operator-innodbcluster-simple-helm.html),

You have two options with MySQL, either deploy with

- A self-signed certificate. This will require setting `tls.useSelfSigned`
- An externally signed certificate. his will require providing a `tls.caSecretName`, `tls.serverCertAndPKsecretName` and `tls.serverCertAndPKsecretName`

You can set these options like this with `--set` like this

```shell
helm install <clustername> mysql-operator/mysql-innodbcluster \
  --set tls.useSelfSigned=true
```

No matter what you'll also always have to provide `credentials.root.password` for this specific chart `--set credentials.root.password=foobar`

---

See also,

- [*"How can I find what options I can set with a `helm install` that the chart provides?"*](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/16066/18965)